# Counting the number of days in a month that have records in my dataset in SQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a MS SQL query I need to figure out to count the number of days in a month in my dataset that has a record and I'm not exactly sure how to proceed with this. Below is an example of my data, but on the out put I just need a number by customer.

Example Data:

```
DATE,ID,CUSTOMER
2023-02-01 00:30:00.000,1,A
2023-02-02 00:30:00.000,2,A
2023-02-03 00:30:00.000,3,A
2023-02-04 00:30:00.000,4,A
2023-02-01 00:30:00.000,5,B
2023-02-01 00:30:00.000,6,B
2023-02-01 00:30:00.000,7,B
2023-02-01 00:30:00.000,8,B
2023-02-02 00:30:00.000,9,A
2023-02-03 00:30:00.000,10,A
```

Expected output

```
Customer, Count
A,4
B,1
```

I'm not sure where to start on this :(

Comment: select datepart(yyyy, date), datepart(month, date), count(distinct cast(date as date)), customer from youtable group by customer, datepart(yyyy, date), datepart(month, date)

Comment: Can you explain the expected output? It doesn't seem to line up with your sample data. It would be better sample data if your data was in more than one month. Why is A not 6 and B not 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `group by` :

with cte to get distinct rows by date and customer, then we get count grouped by customer only.

```
with cte as (
  select DATE, CUSTOMER
  from mytable
  group by DATE, CUSTOMER
)
select CUSTOMER, COUNT(*) as count
FROM cte
group by CUSTOMER;
```

OR

```
with cte as (
  select DISTINCT DATE, CUSTOMER
  from mytable
)
select CUSTOMER, COUNT(*) as count
FROM cte
group by CUSTOMER;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/fTGzuIOh)

If you want to count data per month and per customer :

```
with cte as (
  select DATE, CUSTOMER
  from mytable
  group by DATE, CUSTOMER
)
select convert(varchar(7), DATE, 126) as month, CUSTOMER, COUNT(*) as count
FROM cte
group by convert(varchar(7), DATE, 126), CUSTOMER
order by CUSTOMER
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZvMSKiUe)

Comment: This won't count distinct occurrences per month

Comment: Not sure the OP looking for count per month